# Rsync re-transfers entire file after title change

Tags: server, backup, rsync

According to rsync's man page:

> [Rsync] is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount
> of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between
> the source files and the existing files in the destination.

However, I noticed today that several video files that I had only changed the name of, were re-transferred in their entirety. This seems to contradict the above claim by rsync that it only updates the changes made. Have I made an error in my command that would cause a small text change to the title of a file to cause the re-tranfer of the entire file?

My command:

```
rsync -avz --delete -e ssh /files/tobe/transferrd server@1.1.1.1:/backup/location 1>>/logs/backup.log
```

Comment: `rsync` sees a new file in the source and and extra file in the destination, and proceeds accordingly. It does do delta transfer if the filenames are the same. See also: https://serverfault.com/a/489293/229499

Comment: @muru, would be good to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @muru how about the -y flag? I did some further research and discovered this option. Combined with --delete-after, it seems to work.

Comment: That's what the linked answer suggests. Did you read it?

Comment: @muru I did read it, but your comment suggested no solution. If you make an answer, I'll accept it. You had a good answer but presented it in a strange way.

Comment: @i9pp0 your question didn't ask for a solution. It specifically asked only "Have I made an error in my command that would cause a small text change to the title of a file to cause the re-tranfer of the entire file?" There are always people who insist they don't want alternatives...

Comment: @muru Answer: Yes you have made a mistake by omission. Add the flags -y and --delete-delay or -after, and you will get the result you are looking for, and done.Thanks anyway for the (interestingly packaged) answer.